# vbs - is it possible to hand over IE Object session to MSXML2.XMLHTTP object?

Tags: vbscript

I have a MS SQL box that has a selection of ETL routines to extract data from both Oracle OBIEE via a web interface and Oracle CRM On Demand.

The OBIEE extraction uses an MSXML2.XMLHTTP object, and works flawlessly - user credentials are sent in the URL (all behind our firewall).

Currently my only successful method for CRM On Demand is to use an IE object and mimic the action of logging in, navigating to the report page (an xml url), and saving the resulting rendered page to the filesystem for SQL consumption. The challenge I have is that for larger reports, IE's xml rendering becomes problematic and either times out or is malformed. Additionally the IE object just seems flakey, and will often report that ObjBusy=false and readystate=4 when clearly it is still processing - hence some ugly hacks are needed to check the resulting rendered pages's size on a loop.

Ideal preference would be to use an MSXML2.XMLHTTP object, however I cannot get that object to authenticate. The page I need to login at is https://sso.crmondemand.com/router/logon.jsp

If anyone has any idea how to get past the authentication page, I could simply use existing approaches - otherwise is there an option to somehow pass my authenticated session from the IE object to an MSXML2.XMLHTTP object which would allow for the XML size limits to be negated.

**Relevant MSXML2.XMLHTTP code**

```
Dim xmlHTTP : Set xmlHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0") 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP
Const adTypeBinary = 1 ' ado typelib constants
Const SourceURL = "https:// URL HERE"
xmlHTTP.Open "GET", SourceURL, bGetAsAsync, "userid", "pass"
xmlHTTP.Send
'further code to save file not relevant
```

**Relevant IE Object code**

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objIE.Navigate "https://sso.crmondemand.com/router/logon.jsp"
objIE.visible = true

    Do While objIE.Busy
        wscript.sleep 200
    Loop
    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        wscript.sleep 200
    Loop

objIE.Document.getElementById("IPT_SC_SignIn").innerText = myUserName
objIE.Document.getElementById("IPT_SC_Password").innerText = myPassword
objIE.Document.Forms(0).Submit()

    Do While objIE.Busy
        wscript.sleep 200
    Loop
    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        wscript.sleep 200
    Loop

objIE.Navigate "https:// Path to report... &Action=Download&Format=xml"

    Do While objIE.Busy
        wscript.sleep 200
    Loop
    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 'READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        wscript.sleep 200
    Loop

myVar2 = len(objIE.document.documentElement.innertext)
wscript.sleep 1000

Do While len(objIE.document.documentElement.innertext)<>myVar2
    myVar2 = len(objIE.document.documentElement.innertext)
    wscript.sleep 1000
Loop
'further code to save file not relevant
```

Comment: This seems much more an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks - good suggestion... n00b poster for help :)