# Transfer IE connection to a different object VBA / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vba, excel

I am having difficulty signing in to a company website using POST requests via MSXML2.ServerHTTP60 in VBA or WebRequests in .NET

(there is some validation key sent during log in within the REQUEST string and I can't figure out where it gets this from)

The hacky way I can think to achieve what I want is to automate opening an IE instance, login with element filling and clicking, then pass on the connection to one of the "background" methods like MSXML2.ServerHTTP or WebRequests/WebResponses

**Is there a way to hand over my programatically declared InternetExplorer connection to a different connection hosting class?**

I spotted already [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508717/vbs-is-it-possible-to-hand-over-ie-object-session-to-msxml2-xmlhttp-object) question which is asking the same, thing but we're now 4 years in the future so perhaps there's a chance.

basic idea:

```
objIE.Navigate "https://sso.crmondemand.com/router/logon.jsp"
' login stuff
MyConn = new MSXML2.ServerHTTP60
MyConn = objIE.Connection ' I have no idea really
```

Comment: Hopefully not. If this works please report as a breach.

Comment: You may try to extract cookies and validation key from IE after successfull login, to continue with XHR, or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33236619/2165759). IMO that is bizarre way to do what should work without IE. Just figure out how to get the key via XHR.

Comment: It doesn't seem to come as a response header, cookie, or a string within the body, anything when I first visit the login page, so I assume it carries out a quick javascript function to create a string after clicking login, which is then inserted in to the POST request body with the rest of the stuff needed for login. Thanks for the advice, I guess I'll have to quickly learn javascript and take a stab at XMLHttpRequests